# Select posts with user info and media

Tags: mysql, node.js, lambda, aws-lambda

I need to do the following:

- Select the latest posts (last 10 for example) in post table
- Join the user info from users table
- Join the media avatar for user in media table where type = avatar and media_author = user.id
- Join the media of the post (from 1 to 4 for every single post)

in addiction next I need to filter post of friends and post with preferred hashtag of the user that retrieve the data. I think that all this cannot be done in one single query, right?

In the final solution I need to:

- get the post
- score and order the posts based on some rule (is friends? have hashtag? etc..)
- serve the ordered post with user info and posts info (like count, etc..)

Maybe the better solution is:
only select the post, and for each post do two query to retrieve user and media data?

For now this is the queries that I use for the single post:

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.user_id, posts.privacy, posts.type, posts.published, posts.language, 
       posts.content, posts.date, posts.entity_map, users.username, media.media_url 
  FROM posts 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM users) users 
         ON (users.id = posts.user_id ) 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM media ORDER BY media.id DESC) media 
         ON (media.media_author = posts.user_id AND media.media_type = 'avatar') 
  WHERE posts.id = ?
```

```
SELECT * FROM media WHERE media_parent = ?
```

Have sense to do 20 query to retrieve a list of 10 posts?

here the tables structure:

```
tbl posts

id
content 
date
entity_map
language
privacy 
published
raw_content
type
user_id
```

```
tbl users

id
name
username
```

```
tbl media

id
media_author
media_date
media_parent
media_status
media_type
media_url
```

```
tbl like/love

te be defined, but I think a table with:
id
id_from
id_to
type (like/love/other)
```

Comment: can you share the DB structures, please? @red

Comment: sure, here the tables structure:

```
tbl posts

id
content 
date
entity_map
language
privacy 
published
raw_content
type
user_id
```


`
tbl users

id
name
username
`

`
tbl media

id
media_author
media_date
media_parent
media_status
media_type
media_url
`


`
tbl like/love

te be defined, but I thin a table with:
id
id_from
id_to
type (like/love/other)
`
I post it in an answer to have better formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the latest 10 posts.

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.user_id, posts.privacy, posts.type, posts.published, posts.language, 
       posts.content, posts.date, posts.entity_map, users.username, media.media_url 
  FROM posts 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM users) users 
         ON (users.id = posts.user_id ) 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM media ORDER BY media.id DESC) media 
         ON (media.media_author = posts.user_id AND media.media_type = 'avatar') 
  Order By post.date desc
  limit 10
```

To fetch the media you have to make query for each post. As, sql doesn't facilitate the reference like mongodb.